# Toolbar inside CardView to create a popup menu (overflow icon)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I have a list that looks like google play in a recyclerview with cardview, and works perfect.

I need to add a popup menu (with overflow icon), like this:

[image]

which is the best way to do this ?

I researched and found that there are 2 options:

1 - with a toolbar inside the cardview layout. is there a performanece problem with this solution ?

2 - with a imagebutton or imageview with a icon of the overflow, 
that when you click the menu is created.

I need a solution to be compatible with >= API 10

thanks

Comment: Number 2.
An entire toolbar is unecessary, just use either an `ImageButton` or an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends by your layout.

If you would like a layout like this, with a Toolbar you can achieve it more easily.
[image]

Somenthing like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

   <LinearLayout>

        <Toolbar  android:id="@+id/card_toolbar" />

        //......

   </LinearLayout>

</CardView>

toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.card_toolbar);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){..});
```

If you would like only a popup is more simple to use an image.
Somenthing like:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), mImageButton);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(......);
```

Comment: I second this solution and I think it should work well

Comment: where does the image button come from?

Comment: More convenient way: `popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_restrictions_section);` :)

Answer (score 48):

### Step 1 create Popup Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Not_interasted_catugury"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Never show stories from this category  " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/No_interasted"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="Not Interested"></item>


</menu>
```

### Step 2: Make a Image button in your card

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_detail"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@null"/>
```

> then give a icon from drawable

### Step 3: Inside your holder class

> and set item click listner inside onBindViewHolder

```
mImageButton= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
holder.mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.mImageButton,position);
            }
        });
```

### Step 4: Show pop menu and inflate the xml

```
  private void showPopupMenu(View view,int position) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(),view );
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(position));
        popup.show();
    }
```

### Step 5: Implement the OnMenuItemClickListener

```
     class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        private int position;
        public MyMenuItemClickListener(int positon) {
            this.position=positon;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.Not_interasted_catugury:
                    String RemoveCategory=mDataSet.get(position).getCategory();
                    // mDataSet.remove(position);
                    //notifyItemRemoved(position);
                   // notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());

                    mySharedPreferences.saveStringPrefs(Constants.REMOVE_CTAGURY,RemoveCategory,MainActivity.context);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.No_interasted:
                    mDataSet.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context, "Done for now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.delete:
                    mySharedPreferences.deletePrefs(Constants.REMOVE_CTAGURY,MainActivity.context);
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! Great example, well assembled, saved my time!

Comment: I would advise to use<br>`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` or 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground` as it will show effect when clicked.
Also, if you are using a vector drawable, you should use the following
`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"`  
`android:tint="@color/secondary_text"` 
 to get the right look.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

**list_item:** ( res / layout )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="showOptions"/>    

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**popup_menu:** ( res / menu )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:title="Option1"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:title="Option2"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity:** (add this function anywhere in `MainActivity`)

```
public void showOptions(View view){
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            CardView view = 
           (CardView) ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).getParent();
            int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(cView);  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        item.toString()+" clicked at position"+position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```